# Relation between two sets of positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider two sets $A$ and $B$ with positive measure such that the union is $[0,1]$. Is it true that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 5):

It is true without needing to assume the continuum hypothesis.  A Lebesgue measurable set with positive measure has the same cardinality as $[0,1]$.  My favorite proof (sketch) of this is in [Ehsan's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8972/do-sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-have-same-cardinality-as-r/9088#9088) to a MathOverflow question.  [Andres Caicedo's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8972/do-sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-have-same-cardinality-as-r/26373#26373) and [Fedor Petrov's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8972/do-sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-have-same-cardinality-as-r/26377#26377) answers there also address this, and another proof can be found in the expository article "[Measure and cardinality](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2320153)" by Briggs and Schaffter.  [Joel David Hamkins's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8972/do-sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-have-same-cardinality-as-r/9027#9027) at the MathOverflow question gives a great survey of what can happen with outer measure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, at least if we take the continuum hypothesis. This follows from the *countable subadditivity* of measure, for if we had a countable set we would certainly have a measure of $0$ and the union of any two countable sets is countable. So $A$ and $B$ must be uncountable and with the continuum hypothesis $|A| = |B|$. There is probably a way to do this without assuming the continuum hypothesis, but I haven't thought of it off the top of my head. Of course, even without the CH we would not be able to construct a counterexample.